# In Laravel Eloquent why are some SQL parameters not bound in?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, sql-injection

## Question:

I Noticed interesting behavior in Laravel 7.x where eager loaded relationships don't always have bindings. Is this expected behavior and why would that be the case?

## Code:

#### Actual Queries Laravel Runs:

`select top 100 * from task_view`

`select id, name from task_view where active = ? and student_id in (?, ?, ?)`

`select id, name from task_view where  active = ? and teacher_id in (1 ,2 ,3)`

#### Relationships on Model:

```
public function studentTasks()
{
    return $this->hasMany(StudentTasks::class, 'student_id', 'id');
}
```

```
public function teacherTasks()
{
    return $this->hasMany(TeacherTasks::class, 'teacher_id', 'teacher_id');
}
```

#### Calling Code:

`TaskView::query()->with(['studentTasks', 'teacherTasks']);`

## Additional Points:

I think it may have to do with that where the `localkey` of the relationship (the 3rd argument) is `'id'` then the values aren't bound.

My assumption is that bindings are to prevent sql injection and the [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#introduction) seem to confirm that. If that's the case then why would id's of the model that the relationship is on not need to be bound? I would assume there's still an issue of SQL Injection there.

I have not seen anyone discussing this from my searching around, (Stackoverflow, Laracasts, Laravel docs)

(I printed out the queries using the below code in `AppServiceProvider:boot`)

```
$counter = 0;
\DB::listen(function ($query) use (&$counter) {
    echo 'count: '.++$counter.PHP_EOL;
    // echo memory_get_usage();
    echo $query->sql.PHP_EOL;
    echo implode(',', $query->bindings).PHP_EOL;
});
```

Comment: Eager loading pulls the parent models first and then uses the IDs to populate a second query. You have not provided much info about your tables, models, or what code triggered these queries. Also, you can print out queries by simply doing `Foo::where("bar", 123)->toSql();`

Comment: @miken32 I added the calling code as well as the parent query. I know that Eager first pulls the parent models and uses the IDs to populate subsequent queries, my question is that why for the 2nd query are the parameters for the `in ()` bound but not for the 3rd query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a change introduced into Laravel 5.7.14. The initial pull request [can be found here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/26434). From there you can find more pull requests making updates to the functionality.

It was done as a performance enhancement when needing to eager load a large number of records (many thousands). Instead of having thousands of bound parameters, it puts the raw ids directly in the query. Initially it was done to work around a MySQL PDO bug, but really all database drivers can benefit with not having thousands of bound parameters.

The reason why it does not introduce a SQL injection vulnerability is that:

1. It only replaces the bindings with the raw values when the ids are integers, and
2. It runs all the ids through an integer conversion before adding them to the query.

This is the function that ultimately determines if parameters will be used or if raw ids will be used (https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/Relation.php#L310-L323):

```
/**
 * Get the name of the "where in" method for eager loading.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model  $model
 * @param  string  $key
 * @return string
 */
protected function whereInMethod(Model $model, $key)
{
    return $model->getKeyName() === last(explode('.', $key))
                && in_array($model->getKeyType(), ['int', 'integer'])
                    ? 'whereIntegerInRaw'
                    : 'whereIn';
}
```

And here is the `whereIntegerInRaw()` function that shows the keys are `int` cast before being added into the raw query (https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L961-L985):

```
/**
 * Add a "where in raw" clause for integer values to the query.
 *
 * @param  string  $column
 * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Arrayable|array  $values
 * @param  string  $boolean
 * @param  bool  $not
 * @return $this
 */
public function whereIntegerInRaw($column, $values, $boolean = 'and', $not = false)
{
    $type = $not ? 'NotInRaw' : 'InRaw';

    if ($values instanceof Arrayable) {
        $values = $values->toArray();
    }

    foreach ($values as &$value) {
        $value = (int) $value;
    }

    $this->wheres[] = compact('type', 'column', 'values', 'boolean');

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: The code explains why the 2nd query is parameterized and the 3rd isn't, since in the 3rd the `localKey === model->getKeyName()` the model's key. But if the reasoning was for performance then why only in that case and not 2nd query? For as you explained so eloquently (see what I did) there's no risk of SQL injection.

Comment: @shmuels I would assume because that is the only field that you can verify is an integer without having to query the metadata. The field type of the model key is stored on the model, so there is no penalty to checking if it is set to int. Any other field you'd have to run a separate query against the database to determine the field type. Maybe it could be improved to look to see if there is an "int" cast setup on the model for non-key fields.

Comment: @shmuels Found the PR that added in the check: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/26453. Comment from that PR: "What I missed in the first PR: We also have to check whether the relationship's local key is identical to the model's primary key. If it isn't, we can't rely on getKeyType() and so we can't use a raw query."